# Is there a way to create an object in which the objects class is defined by another variable?

Tags: java, object, if-statement

I have two classes that have some identical methods, the method below should access the methods of one of the two classes based on which checkbox is ticked, However I am having issues passing the objects created within the IF statements into the main body of the method. Is there way to achieve this without copying the main body of the method into both areas? Here is the code:

```
public void populateSupplyChainTextFields() {

    if (jDeliveryCheckBox.isSelected() == true) {
        DeliveryCompany supplyChainMember = new DeliveryCompany();
        supplyChainMember = theDeliveryCompanyList.Find(jSupplyChainSearchBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
    } else {
        Supplier supplyChainMember = new Supplier();
        supplyChainMember = theSupplierList.Find(jSupplyChainSearchBox.getSelectedItem().toString());

    }

    jCategoryTextField.setText(supplyChainMember.getCategory());
    jPriceTextField.setText(String.valueOf(supplyChainMember.getPrice()));
    jUnitCostTextField.setText(String.valueOf(supplyChainMember.getUnitCost()));
```

EDIT**

Based on Salim's response, here is the error message I am receiving:
[image]

To confirm, the method getBusinessName() is in both supplier and deliveryCompany classes.

My apologies if this is a novice question, I am fairly new to Java, any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: Do `DeliveryCompany` and `Supplier` implement a common interface or extend the same base class that defines the `Find()` method?

Comment: they both have their own versions of find, I may have been able to do a parent class if I had thought ahead, but at the moment looking for a way to solve this particular challenge.

Comment: Do you want to return 2 object out of this method, one of type DeliveryCompany and other of type Supplier?

Comment: Depending on the outcome of the if else statement, I would like supplyChainMember object to be either an object of class deliveryCompany or class Supplier, and then go on to access the methods of one of those two classes such as getCategory(), and getPrice(), methods that have identical names in both classes.

Comment: like @ernest_k said the best is to inherit both from a common interface or abstract class. if this doesn't work then you can use a variable of type java.lang.Object to hold either delivery or supplier. Return Object type from this method. You can check type of object using 'classOf' operator and based on which class it is call that method.

Comment: You could create a facade; create a new type which exposes the interface you desire, then have that type handle the determining. Otherwise, you'll need to introduce a common supertype.

Comment: @Salim Thank you for your help, I am wondering what would be the return type of a method of this sort? I have tried public object returnObject();, this has not worked, what would the correct version be?

Comment: @InitialisingAttributes added node snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to inherit DeliveryCompany and Supplier from a common Interface or abstract class. If that doesn't work then you can use `Object` type as last resort.

```
    public Object populateSupplyChainTextFields() {
    Object result = null;

        if (jDeliveryCheckBox.isSelected() == true) {
            DeliveryCompany supplyChainMember = new DeliveryCompany();
            supplyChainMember = theDeliveryCompanyList.Find(jSupplyChainSearchBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
    result = supplyChainMember
        } else {
            Supplier supplyChainMember = new Supplier();
            supplyChainMember = theSupplierList.Find(jSupplyChainSearchBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
    result = supplyChainMember
        }


    return result;

    }
```

```
//Call the method
Object r = populateSupplyChainTextFields();

//Check type and take action
if (r instanceof DeliveryCompany){
    DeliveryCompany supplyChainMember = (DeliveryCompany)r;

        jCategoryTextField.setText(supplyChainMember.getCategory());
        jPriceTextField.setText(String.valueOf(supplyChainMember.getPrice()));
        jUnitCostTextField.setText(String.valueOf(supplyChainMember.getUnitCost())
}
```

Comment: I don't think he's trying to return the object - nothing in the post suggest he's trying to return a value from that method. Seems like he's trying to handle his situation polymorphically. Your code wouldn't compile either (nor would the OP's code), as `supplyChainMember` is not within the scope that `setText` is in. I think the OP wrote his code knowing there would be errors, as he wanted to express what he was trying to achieve.

Comment: Handling polymorphically is better solution. He said he can't do that for some reason. I have been chatting with him.

Comment: Handling it polymorphically would be the only way for his code to compile, unless he introduced a wrapper type. Otherwise, how would he call `jCategoryTextField.setText(supplyChainMember.getCategory())` without errors?

Answer (score 0):

As many have mentioned here, the best thing to do is make `Supplier` and `DeliveryCompany` implement a comment interface or extend a common base class.

If you really cannot do that, and really have to avoid duplication in your blocks, and really if your actual code is more complex than what you posted, you can make your blocks share a variable

*Use a local class to hold data*

```
public void populateSupplyChainTextFields() {

    class Holder {
        String category, price, unitCost;
        Holder(String category, double price, double unitCost){
            this.category = category; 
            this.price = String.valueOf(price); 
            this.unitCost = String.valueOf(unitCost);
        } 
    }

    Holder data;

    if (jDeliveryCheckBox.isSelected()) {
        DeliveryCompany supplyChainMember = new DeliveryCompany().Find(jSupplyChainSearchBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
        data = new Holder(supplyChainMember.getCategory(), supplyChainMember.getPrice(), supplyChainMember.getUnitCost());
    } else {
        Supplier supplyChainMember = new Supplier().Find(jSupplyChainSearchBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
        data = new Holder(supplyChainMember.getCategory(), supplyChainMember.getPrice(), supplyChainMember.getUnitCost());
    }

    jCategoryTextField.setText(data.category);
    jPriceTextField.setText(data.price);
    jUnitCostTextField.setText(data.unitCost);
```

The use of a local class is just my preference, you can choose to use something like a map, instead (surely records will be very handy when introduced):

```
Map<String, String> data;

if (jDeliveryCheckBox.isSelected()) {
    DeliveryCompany supplyChainMember = ...
    data = Map.of("category, supplyChainMember.getCategory(), 
                  "price", String.valueOf(supplyChainMember.getPrice()), 
                  "unitCost", String.valueOf(supplyChainMember.getUnitCost()));
} else {
    Supplier supplyChainMember = ...
    data = Map.of("category, supplyChainMember.getCategory(), 
                  "price", String.valueOf(supplyChainMember.getPrice()), 
                  "unitCost", String.valueOf(supplyChainMember.getUnitCost()));
}

jCategoryTextField.setText(data.get("category"));
jPriceTextField.setText(data.get("price"));
jUnitCostTextField.setText(data.get("unitCost"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your help, its very late in my country so I need to look at this tomorrow. I am working on a project as part of my curriculum and I don't think there is time to comb back through the code and change it so that they are inherited classes.